# Intense fear when focusing infront of me during salah

Tags: salat, jinn, fear

Al Salam Alaykum Brothers. I am a recent revert and I confidently believe that I am the target of several jinn both within me and around me. I have been trying to focus more during salah by focusing on the meaning of my words and praying slowly.

Today I attempted to focus on a visualization of Allah's direction as to feel closer to Allah and commit my prayer to him. I first focused up in the sky while visualizing myself up there as well as to mentally feel my body close to Allah. Then I remembered, while I was in sujood, that we are infront of Allah when praying so I attempted to focus infront. That was when I was met with an incredibly strong fear in my chest. It was the "afraid of being alone in a dark room" fear, or the "can't move in bed because of sleep paralysis" fear. I immediately stopped focusing in that direction and finished my Salah. Brothers, can anyone please help explain to me what this fear was? Was I tapping into a strong jinn that was infront of me at the time (Side note, there was a mirror in front of me that was facing, not directly towards me, but to the side) or was I focusing on Allah's energy, causing the jinn inside me to create this reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uthman b. Abu al-'As reported that he came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)
>   and said:
>
> Allah's Messenger, **the Satan intervenes between me and my prayer** and
>   my reciting of the Qur'an and he confounds me. Thereupon Allah's
>   Messenger (ﷺ) said:, **That is (the doing of a) Satan (devil) who is
>   known as Khinzab, and when you perceive its effect, seek refuge with
>   Allah from it and spit three times to your left.** I did that and Allah
>   dispelled that from me.
>  [Sahih Muslim 2203](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/39/92)

It is Sunnah for the one who is praying, if he notices the whisper of the Satan during his prayer, to seek refuge with Allah from him and to turn his head only, then **spit dryly to his left three times**.

> Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allah have mercy on him) [said](https://islamqa.info/en/144942):
>
> Someone may ask: If a man is praying in congregation, how can he spit
>   dryly to his left? The answer is: If he is the last one on the left,
>   he can spit dryly to his left in any place other than the mosque.
>   Otherwise, he may spit dryly to his left into his garment or his
>   ghutrah (head cover) or a handkerchief. If that is not possible, it is
>   sufficient to turn to his left and say: A‘oodhu Billaahi min
>   al-Shaytaan il-Rajeem (I seek refuge with Allah from the accursed
>   Shaytaan).

May Allah keep you under His Protection. Always try to be in a state of wudu and remember it is equally important to do wudu with khushoo (concentration).

If you haven't already, I'd would also advise you to learn **[Surah Falaq](https://quran.com/113)** and **[Surah Nas](https://quran.com/114)** by heart and recite them when you feel scared along with **[Ayatul Kursi](https://quran.com/2/255)**, These Surahs are a way to seek refuge with Allah from evil of jinns, humans and your own nafs.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, I'll heed your advice. What do you think about the intense fear in front of me? I have had my fair share of waswasa during Salah, and elhamdulellah I sometimes notice and come back. But this level of intense fear was something else!

Comment: Don't worry too much about it. As long as your imaan is strong in Allah nothing can harm you. Alternately it could be also a figment of one's imagination after watching a scary movie or researching too much on that topic.  I also advice if possible to pray Fard prayers in congregation and  not to live alone in a house. Solitary life isn't a good thing for human physiology. Cheers.

Comment: JAK Ahmed for your comments and advice. Taking the different possibilities into account. I must work on strengthening my imaan in sha' Allah.